# Grails: send debug logging to standard out

Tags: logging, grails

When I run my Grails app from my IDE, I want the output to go to the IDE console and be at level Trace.

In grails-app/conf/Config.groovy I've tried a few different things that didn't work, like this:

```
environments {
    development {
        log4j.rootLogger="trace,stdout"
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can try it like this:

```
log4j = {
    appenders {
        console name: "stdout", layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "%c{2} %m%n")
        // This if you need different settings per environment
        environments {                  
            production {
                rollingFile name: "myAppender", maxFileSize: 1024, file: "/tmp/logs/myApp.log"
            }
        }
    }

    root {
        trace "stdout"
    }

    // we are saying default is trace for the console, 
    // but for this package we are setting default as debug
    debug "grails.app.controller"

    environments {
        production {
            // Override previous setting for 'grails.app.controller'
            error "grails.app.controller"
        }
    }
}
```

More examples can be found in the [Grails docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.1.2%20Logging) for Logging.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks.  The stdout appender that removes the timestamp from the log output is a nice touch; I moved it to the development {} block to make sure I get the timestamps in production.